# What techniques are a root cause analysis?

Tags: manual-testing

I am preparing for testing certification and come across the strange question for which I don't have any clue what will be the answer. If anyone give some details it will be helpful .

**Question :** A project had got poor customer satisfaction survey (CSS) rating 3 consecutive times and asked to come reason for this , the project manager decided to do root cause analysis.

Which of the following techniques could he apply here?

1. force field analysis
2. regression analysis
3. fishbone analysis
4. power or interest grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answers is 3.

- **[Fishbone](http://asq.org/learn-about-quality/cause-analysis-tools/overview/fishbone.html)** is one of the most common root cause analysis methods. The other one is the [5-why's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys).
- [Regression analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis): is a set of statistical processes for estimating the relationships among variables. In some cases the root-cause might be clear from data, but most often not.
- [Force Field Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-field_analysis): This is a decision-making method. I am not 100% sure, I think you could try to use it as a root-cause analyses method, but not as a very obvious one.
- [Power/Interest Grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stakeholder_analysis): This is a stakeholder prioritization method, and has nothing todo with root-causes.

Also read [this article about RCA and Force Field Analysis](http://www.weahsn.net/what-we-do/west-of-england-academy/improvement-resources-and-tools/the-improvement-journey/steps-in-the-improvement-journey/define-the-problem/root-cause-analysis/)